# Session doesn't persist in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

#### Here's my AuthController@authentication

```
Session::put('active_user','USER_INFO');
Session::save();
```

#### When I am trying to access session in middleware *Authenticate.php*

```
Log::info(Session::get('active_user'));
```

i got nothing.

#### I used

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session
```

#### Here's my *route.php*

```
Route::post('/login','AuthController@authenticate');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using file as session drive, sometimes it will take little bit of time to write data into the session file(usually milliseconds). So if request dies before writing data into the file it interrupts file writing process and new data may not save into the session. This can be your issue(not 100% sure). You can test it by adding `sleep(1);` after `Session::put(...`. and also you don't have to use `save()` after `put()`

Comment: Thanks Ravisha. I checked session file. Data is saved in session file but i am unable to access it.

Comment: Where did you use Session::get?  On same method after Session::put or another place like on a view?

Comment: I used Session::put() on login and Session::get() in middleware. Both are on different places.

Comment: Did you exclude the login routes from middleware? otherwise it'll Session::get executes before Session::put

Comment: Yes, I exclude it.

Comment: since you are trying to get logged user, why don't you use `\Auth::user()` method